# Screen size is wrong on iPhone 6/iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, screen-size, iphone-6

I just stumbled on something very strange and baffling.

I have code in a client app that loads different images based on screen size.

I have code that uses the current screen to determine the screen size.

On my iPhone 6 (actual device, not simulator) it shows a screen size of 320x568, which is the size of the iPhone 5 screen.

If I run exactly the same code on the iPhone 6 sim, the screen size is reported correctly at 375x667.

To strip away all extraneous details, I just created a new project with the Xcode single view project template. I used Objective-C in case it was a Swift problem. I added a viewWillAppear: method to the view controller that Xcode creates that looks like this:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
  CGSize screenSize = screen.bounds.size;
  _label.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"Screen size = %@",
                NSStringFromCGSize(screenSize)];
}
```

The Xcode template app is set up with an info.plist "UILaunchStoryboardName" value of "LaunchScreen", which actually refers to an XIB file called "LaunchScreen.xib" That XIB displays at launch time on all devices. However, the screen size reported on iPhone 6 is wrong.

What am I missing?!?

Comment: "On my iPhone 6 (actual device, not simulator) it shows a screen size of 320x568, which is the size of the iPhone 5 screen." It sounds like you've got your iPhone 6 "zoomed".

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203073

Comment: I found it, and you were right. The question is how did it get to that setting? I didn't even know that it exists.

Comment: No, the question is not how did it get to that setting. The question is "what am I missing", and I answered that. :))))) Of course the good news is that you can now have yourself a boatload of extra pixels you didn't even know you were missing. Basically you've been carrying around an extra-big iPhone 5 all this time.

Comment: @matt, I honestly never saw that setting until you mentioned it. I have no idea how it got set. Very curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that your iPhone 6 is in zoomed mode, as described here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203073

In that mode, the iPhone 6 effectively thinks it is an iPhone 5 for display purposes (and communicates an iPhone 5-sized screen environment to all apps).

Comment: With the iPhone 6 Plus, zoomed mode is even more extreme; it thinks it is an iPhone 6, which seriously changes what happens on rotation (because we get a different set of size classes), _and it reports 2x resolution instead of 3x resolution_.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to add splash screen IPhone 6 in project